# how to add an onclick event to a Twitter button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter, mootools, twitter-oauth

I would like to do an Ajax request for my Twitter button(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) before going to Twitter.
So before I redirect to the Twitterlogin popup I would like to do something like this(js):

```
  window.addEvent('domready', function () {
           $('twitterbut').setProperties({
                 onclick: "//do ajax call;return (true);"
             });
         });
```

I tried this but it does not work:( How can I add an onclick event similar to above working?

Answer (score 0):

Just read [`Element.Event` documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event) and use the correct method, i.e. `addEvent`:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
     $('twitterbut').addEvent('click', function() {
           //do ajax call
     });
});
```